# Does Microsoft API do throttling to first request?

Tags: azure, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am receiving the following response headers after only the first request to the Microsoft Graph API. I've seen in the documentation that 429 is a reference to throttling but at first request, it doesn't make sense to me.

```
HTTP/1.1 429
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Retry-After: 300
request-id: 983c8fa6-5b66-4ffa-b1ad-33fc0ec25a63
client-request-id: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-9bbf63593fd7
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_5","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
Duration: 298.5416
Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 10:11:01 GMT

{
 "error": {
 "code": "UnknownError",
 "message": "",
 "innerError": {
 "request-id": "983c8fa6-5b66-4ffa-b1ad-33fc0ec25a63",
 "date": "2017-03-10T10:11:01"
 }
}
}
```

I have tried creating a new application in Azure, I have tried request counting and did not found any rogue requests, what could be the meaning of this? What can I do to solve it? Help?

**EDIT**: Example of a request

```
User-Agent: php-calendar/1.0
Authorization: Bearer {my token]
Accept: application/json
client-request-id: XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXbee
return-client-request-id: true
Content-Type: application/json
```

*payload:*

```
   {
    Subject: "stackoverflow Teste",
    Body: {
        ContentType: "HTML",
        Content: ""
    },
    Start: {
        DateTime: "2017-03-10T13:41:00+01:00",
        TimeZone: "Europe/Paris"
    },
    End: {
        DateTime: "2017-03-10T14:40:00+01:00",
        TimeZone: "Europe/Paris"
    },
    IsAllDay: false,
    IsCancelled: false,
    organizer: {
        emailAddress: {
            address: "christophe.soares@pingpost.pt",
            name: "Christophe Soares"
        }
    },
    sensitivity: "Normal",
    Location: {
        DisplayName: "Índico",
        Address: {
            street: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            countryOrRegion: "",
            postalCode: ""
        }
    },
    Attendees: [
        {
            Type: "Required",
            status: {
                time: "2017-03-10T15:41:48Z",
                response: "1"
            },
            emailAddress: {
                address: "christophe.soares@pingwlt.com",
                name: "Christophe Soares"
            }
        },
        {
            Type: "Required",
            emailAddress: {
                address: "roompresence@pingwlt.com",
                name: "Graça Silva"
            }
        },
        {
            Type: "Resource",
            status: {
                time: "2017-03-10T15:41:48Z",
                response: "3"
            },
            emailAddress: {
                address: "indico@pingwlt.com",
                name: "Room-Índico"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Besides, it would seem that if the exact same request is sent about 5 minutes later, this request works fine. I am baffled with this, don't know what else to try.

Comment: I think ``UnknownError`` means something other than throttling. Can you provide the request also?

Comment: @RasmusW I edited with an example request.